# Is there a BASIC dialect which uses "==" as the comparison operator?

Tags: equals, basic, assignment-operator, comparison-operators

Anyone who grew up on BASIC, and later switched to another language, had a real difficulty getting used to "(a == b)" rather than "(a = b)" to test for equality.

Is there a dialect of BASIC which uses the "==" operator for comparisons rather than overloading "=" for assignments and comparisons? Or - and maybe this is stretching it - is there an implementation which might be easily hackable to use this behavior (to change the tokens recognized by the parser?)

This can be a DOS/Windows/Linux implementation, and doesn't have to be terribly fully-featured. (I'm using this for instructional purposes.)

Comment: Another comment.... If you want to instruct, I like python. It's a bit more forgiving. Has higher-level concepts, and could be used for more complex projects as the student's skillset matures.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the reason for the double-equal in algol family to distinguish equality from assignment? What, then, would you have us do with the "LET" keyword? Abandon it? It was my favorite keyword! So permissive...

http://www.freebasic.net/

Open source, FTW!

Comment: Any thoughts on where in the source (that I am browsing but is heavily uncommented) I might find what I'm looking for?

Comment: It works already... See ast-node-misc.bas in the compiler code (round about line 442)

Comment: I see that... but it doesn't work. As in, the freebasic compiler gives a syntax error when I try to use ==. (Also... that doesn't "disable" the "=" for use as a comparator). I will keep digging through code, but let me know if you come up with something!